# problem in matching two sets of particles

Tags: functions, function-construction, machine-precision

I have been trying to simulate a simple system in which there are two set of particles. One kind of particles are localized on the boundary of a circle (shown in purple below), whereas the second kind can be either inside or outside of the boundary (delineated in blue).

I will post the simplified version of what is bugging me so as to avoid unnecessary confusion with detalied code and enable the readers to effectively answer my query.

Consider that I generate the two particles using the following commands:

```
particles = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {200, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 2];

membrane = Table[SetAccuracy[RandomPoint[Circle[]], 3], 100];

particlemap = Thread[{Range@Length[particles], particles}];
```

we can see it visually:

```
Graphics[{Darker@Purple, Point@membrane, Blue, Point@particlemap}]
```

[image]

Now i can find the blue particle interacting with the purple particle using the following piece of code:

```
p = Reap[Function[{particle},

  particleposition = particle[[2]];
  Sow[particle[[1]], 
   Select[membrane, # === particleposition &]]] /@ particlemap
][[2]]

(* {{80}} was the index of the particle that was interacting with 
the membrane for the example posted *)
```

Now I can also create an association to extract the coordinates of interacting
particles

```
association = Association@Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &, particlemap];

interactingParticlePos = association[#]&/@(Flatten@p)

(* {0.57, 0.83} was the interactingParticlePos *)
```

plugging this value back we can find that `Position` can get the index back

```
Position[particles, interactingParticlePos]
(* {{80}} as we expected *)
```

**However the anomaly is that we do not find the position of the point in membrane**,

```
Position[membrane, interactingParticlePos]
(* {} *)
```

This should not be the case because earlier the `Select` command found a match between the `membrane` and the `particlemap`

Moreover,

```
MemberQ[membrane, interactingParticlePos]
(*False*)
MemberQ[particles,interactingParticlePos]
(*True*)
```

Can someone Kindly let me know how I can get the index of the position shared by `particles` and `membrane` for the membrane. Furthermore, why is `Position` and `MemberQ` not able to find a match whereas `Select` could?

My hunch is that it has something to do with the way i am setting `WorkingPrecision` and `SetAccuracy` but not sure.

**I am trying to do a reaction diffusion simulation but this seems to be the key step. If I do not use** `WorkingPrecision` and `SetAccuracy` ** then the** `RandomReal` and `RandomPoints` **are generated to machineprecision which makes it impossible for the two kinds of particles to find eachother**

Many thanks in return for the help !

Comment: Instead of messing with precisions, why not create a `NearestFunction`? Then use that, with some epsilon threshold, to determine when particles have in effect collided.

Comment: yeah actually that might do too. thanks :)  but i am really interested in why the above mentioned problem is the case

Comment: It seems this falls into a gray area, where `SameQ` says one thing and whatever internals are in use by pattern matching for numbers says another. It is really not a reliable way to try to do this. Also it's slower than using a `NearestFunction`, which will matter if the size of these sets is scaled upward.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice Daniel. I have implemented using the `NearestFunction` approach as you suggested

Comment: Hi Daniel, could you kindly check this new post: its a different question regarding the same project. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132525/the-curious-case-of-missing-random-walking-particles-in-the-box

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Position[particles, #] & /@ interactingParticlePos
```

And this:

```
MemberQ[membrane, #] & /@ interactingParticlePos
MemberQ[particles, #] & /@ interactingParticlePos
```