# Flatten:flpi message generated with RotationTransform with more points

Tags: function-construction, simulation, rotation

I am doing a very small job of making points rotate or diffuse randomly on a circle.

I generate the particles using `positions = RandomPoint[Circle[],100]`
and create an identity for individual particles using

`indexed = MapIndexed[First@#2 -> #1 &, positions];`

**Code for rotating particles**

```
(* strategy : get all the points. rotate them using a random number
(angle) generated from a Gaussain function. export updated points out
of the module *)

BrownianWalkCircle[particlepos_, particleind_] := 
Module[{newposition, index, angle, center},
center = {0, 0};
angle = Pi/1800.; (* 0.1 degree rotation about center {0,0} *)

newposition = 
RotationTransform[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, angle]],center][#] & /@particlepos; 
(* in the line above we generate the new position *)

index = Thread[Range[Length@particleind] -> newposition]; (* new
position associated with particle name or identity *)

{newposition, index}] /; Length@particlepos > 0
```

Now I am using the following code to draw the circle and points that are in motion on the circle

```
Monitor[For[i = 1, i < 3500, i++,
{positions, indexed} = BrownianWalkCircle[positions, indexed];
g = Graphics[{Circle[], Red, Point@positions}]
], g]
```

**Problem**

I get the following message almost always when i use 100 particles:

`Flatten::flpi: Levels to be flattened together in {{1,3},{2,4}} should be lists of positive integers. >>`

The simulation runs fine (see the picture below)

[image]

**I never get this message with fewer particles say if i use 40 particles instead of 100.**

Can anyone suggest what is the reason and how this message can be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

(I have given more thought to the problem and have come up with what I think is a better answer.)

I have good news and bad news.

First the good news.

1. I was able to compress your code into something very simple. That eliminated a lot code that might have been harboring a bug that was causing the messages.
2. I can tell you how to avoid the error messages.

Now the bad news.

1. I could not determine where the error messages are coming from.
2. I can't give a fix, only a work around.

#### Code using Do to perform the iteration

```
With[{angle = 1/2 Degree}, 
  brownianWalkCircle[pts : {{_, _} ..}] := 
    RotationTransform[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, angle]]][#] & /@ pts]
```

`Do` is simpler and quicker than `For`.

```
With[{nPts = 123, nSteps = 100},
  Module[{p, g},
    p = RandomPoint[Circle[], nPts];
    Monitor[
      Do[
        p = Quiet[brownianWalkCircle[p]];
        g = Graphics[{Circle[], Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[p]}], 
       nSteps],
    g]]]
```

The above is all the code that is needed to show both the problem and the work-around, which is adding the `Quiet` wrapper. When messages are coming from somewhere deep in Wolfram's code, this is the bandage to apply.

#### Code using Nest

I include this as a variant approach to iterating over many steps.

```
With[{nPts = 123, nSteps = 100},
  Module[{p, g},
    Monitor[
      Nest[
        (p = Quiet[brownianWalkCircle[#]]; 
         g = Graphics[{Circle[], Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[p]}];
         p) &,
        RandomPoint[Circle[], nPts],
        nSteps];,
   g]]]
```

#### Note

I recant on my previous assertion that the error message is coming from  `Graphics`. See my revised code above, where wrapping `brownianWalkCircle` with `Quiet` is sufficient to suppress the error messages. Frankly, I can't really say anything about how the messages get produced.

Comment: You don't really need to use `Map[]` with `RotationTransform[]`; thus, `With[{angle = Degree/2}, brownianWalkCircle[pts : {{_, _} ..}] := RotationTransform[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, angle]]][pts]]`

Comment: Thanks so much @m_goldberg. I am accepting your answer. And also thanks a lot for the cleaner code. Btw if you look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132525/the-curious-case-of-missing-random-walking-particles-in-the-box/132686#132686 do you think i should avoid global variables and the For loop used in this question

Comment: @m_goldberg actually in the above question what i did was create a bunch of global variable and then update the values of those variables in each iteration in the `For` loop like in the question posted above. The methods that update the values use functional strategy. Do you think that should be avoided as well

Comment: @m_goldberg perhaps something like `Nest[(all functions in succession), initial configuration of the system, steps for iteration]`. what do you think?

Comment: @J.M. I had already tried what you suggest. It does not work because `NormalDistribution[0, angle]]` only gets evaluated once, not for each point. Removing `[#] &` is something I would do, if it weren't for `Monitor`. That funny, seemingly unnecessary bit helps `Monitor` to display more events.

Comment: @AliHashmi. I am not saying you should always avoid global variables. They certainly have their legitimate uses. But none were necessary in the test code, and I don't like to use them when there is no need. You might find `Do` a good iterator, suited to your work, and easier to use than `Nest`. See the updates I have made above.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I managed to implement the code with Nest and it looks cleaner without global variables. But next time if i have to choose an iterator i will be reminded of your comment.